# Ansible equivalent of Puppet's "unless" attribute

Tags: ansible, puppet

In Puppet, when using the [exec](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.4/reference/type.html#exec) resource, you can specify an "[unless](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.4/reference/type.html#exec-attribute-unless)" attribute. The Puppet `exec` will not run unless the "unless" command exits with status 0.

Puppet example:

```
exec { 'Make sure frob is installed':
  command => 'apt-get install -y frob',
  unless  => 'frob --version',
}
```

Ansible's [command module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html) has a "creates" option that looks for a file, but I don't see an "unless" option.

How can I specify a Puppet-style "unless" attribute in Ansible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ansible has [conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html) that you can apply to tasks.  However, `when` doesn't map directly to Puppet's `unless`, as it operates on Ansible variables, not shell commands.

However, you can still do what you want, just not quite as directly.  Here's an example from the documentation:

```
tasks:
  - command: /bin/false
    register: result
    ignore_errors: True
  - command: /bin/something_else
    when: result|succeeded
```